# Wordpress Nextgen Gallery Slideshow - How to add simple navigation buttons/arrows?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins, nextgen-gallery

I am looking to use Nextgen Gallery slideshow in a Wordpress website to display a large image gallery of 50+ high resolution images, but Nextgen gallery only lets one advance to the next image in the gallery by clicking on the image. There is no navigation buttons or arrows that lets one go back and forth in the gallery. I have looked all over the web and unfortunately my jQuery knowledge just isn't up to par to tackle this issue on my own.

I am trying to make the Nextgen Gallery slideshow appear like how Nivo Slider does - http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/ - with the prev/next arrows and the pagination buttons

The reason I am using Nextgen Gallery is due to how it loads images - it loads 3 to 4 images at a time which drastically reduces page load time. Other image galleries that offer navigation functions freeze up the homepage due to trying to finish loading all the images at once.

Edit: We are staying away from the Nextgen Flash gallery function

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Kayla

Comment: Plz chk this link http://nextgen-gallery.com/slideshow/nextgen-monoslideshow/ . The link is showing those slideshows having next/back options. You need to customize those according to your requirement. Try to add "preset" options in your slideshow shortcode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I apologize as I forgot to mention that we are staying away from using Flash...

Comment: Here is the solution! Ended up hiring a dev to implement it - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-ngg-slideshow-enable-prev-next?replies=2